# textarea not changing after inserting text

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a function that changes the textarea height when reaching 25 characters, and it works fine when you write the text.

Problem is, I need to have some predefined replies and I am doing that on a modal that inserts the text, but the function does not detect that and doesn't resize. If you insert the text and then write one letter, it expands.

My function:

```
adjust() {

  let ionTextarea = document.getElementById('myInput');
  let textarea = ionTextarea.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
  if (textarea) {
    if (textarea.value.length > 25) {
      textarea.style.overflow = 'scroll';
      textarea.style.height = '200px';
    } else {
  textarea.style.height = '20px';
}
}return;}
```

textarea does return the same data in both cases: writing and inserting text (so styling should work), but it does not change when you insert it.

I tried with (ionChange)="", (keyup)=""... but doesn't work.

```
<ion-textarea id="myInput" #chat_input placeholder="Mensaje" [(ngModel)]="editorMsg" rows="1" (ionFocus)="scrollToBottom()" (ionChange)="adjust()"></ion-textarea>
```

Could someone help me? Thanks

Ps: I am using ionic framework

Sending data when closing popover:

```
close(item) {
  let data = item;
  this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data);
}
```

Filling textarea with the data (and calling resize function):

```
popover.onDidDismiss(data => {
  this.editorMsg = data;
  this.adjust();
})
```

Comment: Add a call to `adjust` in the code that inserts the text. There is no simple event you can use, but since you make the text change via code, you also know when to call `adjust`: so just do it then.

Comment: it is a hack, but perhaps (it worked for me in a different context) after you set the stuff manually, you could send a space and a backspace with sendkeys, then it will know something changed

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

HTML:

```
<ion-textarea id="myInput" #chat_input placeholder="Mensaje" [(ngModel)]="editorMsg" rows="1" (ionFocus)="scrollToBottom()" (ionChange)="adjust()"></ion-textarea>
```

CSS:

```
#myInput {
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('myInput') myInput: ElementRef;


adjust() {
//let textarea: any = event.target;
let ionTextarea = document.getElementById('myInput');
let textarea = ionTextarea.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];

console.log(textarea);

if (textarea) {
  if (textarea.value.length > 25) {
    textarea.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    this.myInput.nativeElement.style.height = '200px';
  } else {
    this.myInput.nativeElement.style.height = '20px';
  }
}
return;}
```

For changing **dynamically & in real-time** (Better Approach) do something like this:

HTML:

```
<textarea #myInput id="myInput" rows="1" maxLength="500" (keyup)="resize()" [(ngModel)]="myStuff"></textarea>
```

CSS:

```
#myInput {
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('myInput') myInput: ElementRef;

resize() {
    this.myInput.nativeElement.style.height = this.myInput.nativeElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

For more info read [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ion-textarea-resize-height-dynamically).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still does not work. It's like it doesn't detect the changes in the textarea. It does work when you write text, but not when I insert it from the popover... :(

Comment: @Daniel what and how are you inserting from the popover?

Comment: @Daniel change `[(ngModel)]` to `[ngModel]`